# Android Console Log Understanding - Chromium/YT

Tags: android, logging, chromium, remote-control, oneplusone

While developing my android app for bachelor thesis, I received this log line in the console:

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(89)] "[1.724s] [yt.mdx.remote] remote:  --
>   with channel params:
>   {"device":"REMOTE_CONTROL","id":"ac6b1eee-9f21-47a0-b04a-69b6bf98b3e5","name":"Desktop","app":"youtube-desktop"}

I don't understand what application triggered it and what it has to do between chromium, remote control, and youtube desktop app.

I have a OPO running CM11s, Chrome installed by default, not installed chromium, and a never used Microsoft RD Client (still need to try it).

My question is just out of curiosity and kwoledge of what is happening in my phone and if I should be concerned about it (just in case!)

Thank you very much!

Comment: This could be from the google play service you are using, probably you have advertisement using admob

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Thank you!